# Determine whether the sequence is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is the sequence:

$$a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^2+1}$$

How to do the limit?

Comment: Hint: try factoring out the highest power of $n$ in the numerator and in the denominator, then simplifying before taking the limit.

Comment: What have you *tried* before asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we get
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^2+1}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^2}}{\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{n^4+1}{n^4}}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^4}}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1+0}}{1+0}=1.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Use equivalents, $\sqrt{n^4+1}\sim n^2$ and $n^2+1\sim n^2$.

Comment: While this is perfectly valid, I seriously doubt the OP has encountered asymptotic equivalents yet (based on the question itself, which does not look like something coming after a chapter introduced these asymptotic notions).

Comment: You are probably right, @Gecko should post an answer!

Answer (score -1):

Observe that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^2=\lim \frac{n^4+1}{n^4+2n^2+1}=1.
$$
Since $a_n>0$ and the function $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous for $x>0$, it follows that $a_n$ converges to $1$ as well.

Furthermore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent (but this might not have been what you were asking for?)

Comment: "Sequence $\neq$ series."

Comment: Either the question was edited or I misread the title as series instead of sequence. In any case, I answered both questions: the display shows how to find the limit of the sequence, showing that it is convergent, and the next line points that this implies the series diverges. While your comment is true, I'm not sure it applies...

Comment: Well, your answer does not actually show convergence of the sequence, something is missing (and, AFAIK, the question hasn't been edited): the sequence $(b_n)_n$ defined by $b_n=(-1)^n$ definitely satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n^2=1$ as well.

Comment: Right, obviously we are using the fact that $a_n>0$ and the square root function is continuous. Since it confused you, I added it to the answer.

Comment: It didn't confuse me. I was just pointing out that without this, the proof was flawed.

Comment: I think you are being a little pedantic in this chain of comments...

Comment: ?! Your original answer missed the question. I pointed it out, and then you pretended it was because the OP edited their question, which was not the case. Then you edited your answer to provide a proof which was mathematically faulty (and that matters, since the OP is clearly trying to learn some basics about convergence, at which stage it is of paramount importance to be rigorous). And **I** am being pedantic?